# Queue-ing Byte arrays trouble. (Queue<Byte[]>)

Tags: c#, queue

I'm trying to create queue of a byte arrays of commands that I receive by TCP Socket.
The data is received by socket, and then is Queued by "addto_queue".
But every time i "Peek" or "Dequeue", I find out that the array in the queue is empty.

```
//--------------------------------

Queue<Byte[]> myQ;

public void init()
{
  myQ = new Queue<Byte[]>();
}

public void addto_queue(Byte[] data)
{
  myQ.Enqueue(data);
  MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
}

//-------------------------------
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is the `MessageBox.Show` when adding also empty? Also, for debugging there I would use `BitConverter.ToString(data)` to see the actual binary string.

Comment: Yes, the message box is showing the data.

Comment: can we see the actual business logic calling `init` and `addto_queue`?

Comment: just names while debugging.

Comment: huh? No, I mean there's not enough in the code snippet you posted to begin dissecting the problem

Comment: there is nothing more... all the other code is tcp socket, that works great.